# Switch site language to en_ZA

Tags: multi-language, language

I've translated my site to English/South Africa - there's different translation for regular English - but I cannot figure out how to switch the site to `en_ZA`.

I have multisite install, and the domain I need to switch the language for is domain.com/za.

How to do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a locale filter, please see:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale

for an example,

Enjoy,

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to the WP_CONFIG

```
define ('WPLANG', 'en_ZA');
```

For more info check out http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Language-in-Wordpress

Comment: Thanks, but I need to switch the lang for only the `za` blog. I tried `if (get_current_blog_id() == 15) define ('WPLANG', 'en_ZA');`, which doesn't work, as the Wordpress functions aren't defined yet...